# Is there a Borders common MFC dialog?

Tags: mfc, dialog, border

Does anyone know if there is a common Borders dialog that we can harness for our own MFC apps? Like this one:

[image]

Comment: Not sure that usage of such a resource would be common enough to formally add such to the Common Dialogs. But you may be able to extract the dialog resource template from Excel.exe (or whatever) as a starting-point for your own implementation.

Comment: @AdrianMole Don't think it is worth the hasstle. Not to worry. Stick with my ComboBoxes. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a custom dialog implemented by Microsoft Excel. There's neither a [common dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/win-common-dlg) provided by the system nor an implementation shipped through MFC that offers this functionality.